# Как реализовать метод giveMoney?

Tags: php, php7

Как реализовать публичный метод `giveMoney` который передает деньги от одного пользователя к другому (нельзя передать больше денег чем есть на балансе)?
Во время передачи денег выводится сообщение “Пользователь name перечислил $amount пользователю name”
Пользователю нельзя изменить баланс любым другим способом кроме `giveMoney`.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

class User{
private $name;
private $balance;
private $amount = 150;

function __construct($name,$balance){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->balance = $balance;
}

public function printStatus(){
    echo "У пользователя ".$this->name." сейчас на счету ".$this->balance;
}

public function giveMoney(){
    //
    //
    //
}

}

$user1 = new User("Max",100);
$user2 = new User("Anton",1000);
```

Comment: `Структуры данных php` - поиск. После ознакомления вопрос должен отпасть. Не отпал - читайте еще раз, на другом источнике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function giveMoney(string $user, float $amount): string
{
    if($amount > $this->balance){
        return 'Недостаточно средств!'."<br/>";
    }

    $this->balance -= $amount;
    $user->balance += $amount;
    return "Пользователь ".$this->name." перечислил ".$amount." пользователю ".$user->name."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: если что, это учебная задача-решение, не про настоящие системы